# Выполнение обычного метода как статического. Разница Windows и Linux

Tags: python, linux

Есть отдельный модуль XMLValidator.py с одноименным классом в соседней папке. Импортирую его и использую модуль. В Windows следующий код работал без проблем:

```
from libraries.XMLValidator import XMLValidator
#...
XMLValidator.validate_xml(xml_schema_file, xsd_schema_file)
```

В Linux стала падать ошибка:

> unbound method validate_xml() must be called with XMLValidator
>   instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Судя по всему, решением могло бы стать создание экземпляра класса и уже из него тянуть функцию (ну или сделать её статической).

```
sys.path.insert(0, './libraries')
from XMLValidator import XMLValidator
#...
XMLValidator1 = XMLValidator()
XMLValidator1.validate_xml(xml_schema_file, xsd_schema_file)
```

Но в таком случае падает ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "install.py", line 176, in
>   
>       XMLValidator1.validate_xml(xml_schema_file, xsd_schema_file)
>
> TypeError: validate_xml() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Как быть? Вероятно, я не правильно понимаю смысл первой ошибки.

Comment: Нашел что-то похожее в английской части сайта, но с трудом могу в английский.

Comment: Есть версия, что трабла в версиях python. На windows стоит 3.6.2, на linux (RedHat) стоит 2.7.5